# How to change the mac address of Bluetooth dongle in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bluetooth, dongle

i have just bought 12  bluetooth dongles  and they all have the same mac address. 
How can i change them on ubuntu linux?

Comment: Probably because it's not about programming (that's what StackOverflow is for). It might be a great question for askubuntu.com and/or superuser.com (they're other sites on StackExchange that work like this). If they asked how to do it in Python or something, that might be different. I think it should have been migrated, rather than closed, unless they thought the questioner would reword it to be about programming. @Ataraxia

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use bdaddr:

```
bdaddr -i hci0 00:01:E3:64:DD:9B
```

From: http://blog.petrilopia.net/hacking/change-your-bluetooth-device-mac-address/

Comment: *Note:* if one is using this method on a VM like VirtualBox, just virtually un-checking bluetooth USB dongle and rechecking USB dongle (to emulate unplug and plug) doesn't work. One has to physically unplug and re-plug the dongle then connect to VM before the new MAC takes effect.

Answer (score -2):

Provided that they are represented using an interface visible in `ip addr` (though this might be limited to the IP-over-BT layers), you can

```
ip link set dev foo0 addr 11:22:33:44:55:66
```